# Wordpress: meta_query with custom fields ( posts get by sub-field ) (WP_QUERY)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I create in WP a Custom Field with name='add_info' (type=Repeater)
This field has a sub-field called comments (name=ai_comment, type=text)

How i can get only posts with comments != NULL / EMPTY?

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'cpt_articles', 
            'meta_query'        => array(
                                        array(
                                            'key'       => 'add_info_%_ai_comment', 
                                            'value'     => '""',
                                            'compare'   => '!='
                                        )
                                   ),
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page'    => 10,
        );
```

The little bit strange solution ( additional_tests_%_acomment ) i have found here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-query-posts-filtered-by-custom-field-values/#example-5

But doesnt works... display empty

here is the dump..

```
string(431) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'cpt_articles' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'add_info_%_ai_comment' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) != '\"\"' ) ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

Comment: try with: `'value'     => '',` instead the 2 double quotes.

Comment: @lolka_bolka i have already this try... output: AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) != '' ) this is very buggy

i have also try 'value' => 'NULL' with 'compage' => 'IS NOT' and 'compage' => '!='

doesnt work :-/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meta Query Posts by Sub Field Value ACF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312487/meta-query-posts-by-sub-field-value-acf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work I think:

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID"
    . " FROM wp_posts"
    . " INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )"
    . " WHERE 1=1"
    . " AND wp_posts.post_type = 'cpt_articles'"
    . " AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')"
    . " AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'add_info_%_ai_comment' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != '')"
    . " GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
```

You are not applied that filter, what is in the tutorial. So your `wp_postmeta.meta_key =` won't replaced by `wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE` and the wildcards are not works. Second, check, how I use the `NOT NULL` and the string comparison.

You do not need to cast your field to string, since it's already a `LONGTEXT` field. Try this directly in MySql and tell me the results in the comment. (When you want to use it in mysql directly, first echoes it in PHP, this is a PHP string in my answer).

Comment: thanks for your reply.Yes i know the correct SQL statemant IS NOT NULL :-) thats was only the dump from WP_QUERY. Thats the reason why iam writting to you "very buggy" from WP (last comment) ........

your query works with a little fix very nice ( you have by the last AND one comma too much)

now i become the correct result of 2 postings with comments => n1 ..........

is it possible that i use the $sql with WP_Query so that wp building the normal object and i can request vars like <?php the_title() ?> ?

Comment: okay i have now added the function in functions.php. You have right...... i forget the adding the filter. thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the version of wordpress I am using (4.9.4) the subfields in ACF are saved with a '0' between the fields. I first thought that the '%' would also catch the '0', but from testing I disovered that it (in my case) does not.

So in my case it was:

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type'     => 'trainingen',
                        'order'         => 'ASC',
                        'meta_query'    => array(
                                                'key' => 'data_en_tijden_0_locatie',
                                                'compare' => '=',
                                                'value' => '"'.get_the_ID().'"'
                                                )
```

If this does not work you can also use a custom SQL query, like:

```
SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` p INNER JOIN wp_posts w on w.ID=p.meta_value WHERE meta_key="data_en_tijden_0_locatie" and w.ID="'.get_the_ID().'"
```

NOTE: I use the ACF relational field, not the post_object field. This field can be configured to return the post_id, instead of the whole object. Thus simplifying the comparison.

I hope this helps you!