# Meta Query Posts by Sub Field Value ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am attempting to query posts by those with sub field values of 'audi'. I have looked and looked but cannot find an answer. The $args I have are below, and posts exist in the database which match 'audi' as the value for sub field 'model' of repeater 'cars'.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'manufacturers',
    'meta_query' => array(
       array(
        'key' => 'cars_%_model',
        'value' => 'audi',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
       )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Any hints as to where this code falls down would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spent a few hours on this and have a solution for you:

First thing you need to do is setup a filter which replaces '=' comparisons with 'LIKE' comparisons (include this above your previous code):

```
function my_posts_where( $where ) {
     $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'cars_", "meta_key LIKE 'cars_", $where);
     // note if using wordpress < v4.8.3 add a % to the meta key like this: meta_key = 'cars_%",...
     return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
```

Now all you need to do is update your meta_query comparison to '=':

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'manufacturers',
    'meta_query' => array(
       array(
        'key' => 'cars_%_model',
        'value' => 'audi',
        'compare' => '='
       )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This is included in the [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/#examples) however the documentation does not mention the updates following Wordpress 4.8.3 [which is mentioned here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/percentage-in-sql/).